# Subfigure has space in the center

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, subfloats

I have a subfigure in my tex document:

```
\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigmatrix}{2}
        \subfigure{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img/phi_env_0.pdf}}
        \subfigure{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img/Wannier_R=-5.pdf}}
        \subfigure[Bloch function with $k = 1.54$]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img/phi_env_1.pdf}}
        \subfigure{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img/Wannier_R=-1.pdf}}
        \subfigure{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img/phi_env_2.pdf}}
        \subfigure{
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img/Wannier_R=3.pdf}}
    \end{subfigmatrix}
    \caption{Baseline accuracy (several classifiers and number of observations).}
    \label{fig:bloch_wannier}
\end{figure}
```

As you can see this leaves a big gap in the middle. I would like this gap to disappear an then the column to be centered. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: I think that this link you could be help. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335167/how-to-add-nine-figures-to-a-two-column-page

Comment: Which package defines `subfigmatrix`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - The package is called [`subfigmat`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigmat)

Comment: You could replace the \subfigurematrix with a tabular.  The subcaptions (text only) would go in their own lines.

Comment: `subfigmat` package is buggy: (i) documentation is rather poor and misleading (`\setlength{\sfmcolsep}{\hspace{0.2in}}` cannot work), (ii) distance between figures are hard coded and can't be changed (regardless that documentation claim differently). better is used one of solutions from link of *Sebastiano* comment or consider *John Kormylo* advice.